# alsa - mem leak?

Tags: linux, memory-leaks, valgrind, alsa

I've been chasing a memory leak (reported by 'valgrind --leak-check=yes') and it appears to be coming from ALSA. This code has been in the free world for some time so I'm guessing that it's something I'm doing wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <alsa/asoundlib.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    snd_ctl_t *handle;

    int err = snd_ctl_open( &handle, "hw:1", 0 );
    printf( "snd_ctl_open: %d\n", err );

    err = snd_ctl_close(handle);
    printf( "snd_ctl_close: %d\n", err );
}
```

The output looks like this:

```
[root@aeolus alsa]# valgrind --leak-check=yes ./test2
==16296== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==16296== Copyright (C) 2002-2012, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==16296== Using Valgrind-3.8.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==16296== Command: ./test2
==16296==
snd_ctl_open: 0
snd_ctl_close: 0
==16296==
==16296== HEAP SUMMARY:
==16296==     in use at exit: 22,912 bytes in 1,222 blocks
==16296==   total heap usage: 1,507 allocs, 285 frees, 26,236 bytes allocated
==16296==
==16296== 4 bytes in 2 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 1 of 62
==16296==    at 0x4007100: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:270)
==16296==    by 0x340F7F: strdup (in /lib/libc-2.5.so)
==16296==    by 0x624C6B5: ??? (in /lib/libasound.so.2.0.0)
==16296==    by 0x624CA5B: ??? (in /lib/libasound.so.2.0.0)
==16296==    by 0x624CD81: ??? (in /lib/libasound.so.2.0.0)
==16296==    by 0x624F311: snd_config_update_r (in /lib/libasound.so.2.0.0)
==16296==    by 0x624FAD7: snd_config_update (in /lib/libasound.so.2.0.0)
==16296==    by 0x625DA22: snd_ctl_open (in /lib/libasound.so.2.0.0)
==16296==    by 0x804852F: main (test2.cpp:9)
```

and continues for some pages to

```
==16296== 2,052 bytes in 57 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 62 of 62
==16296==    at 0x4005EB4: calloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:593)
==16296==    by 0x624A268: ??? (in /lib/libasound.so.2.0.0)
==16296==    by 0x624A38F: ??? (in /lib/libasound.so.2.0.0)
==16296==    by 0x624CA33: ??? (in /lib/libasound.so.2.0.0)
==16296==    by 0x624CCC9: ??? (in /lib/libasound.so.2.0.0)
==16296==    by 0x624CD81: ??? (in /lib/libasound.so.2.0.0)
==16296==    by 0x624F311: snd_config_update_r (in /lib/libasound.so.2.0.0)
==16296==    by 0x624FAD7: snd_config_update (in /lib/libasound.so.2.0.0)
==16296==    by 0x625DA22: snd_ctl_open (in /lib/libasound.so.2.0.0)
==16296==    by 0x804852F: main (test2.cpp:9)
==16296==
==16296== LEAK SUMMARY:
==16296==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==16296==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==16296==      possibly lost: 22,748 bytes in 1,216 blocks
==16296==    still reachable: 164 bytes in 6 blocks
==16296==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==16296== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
==16296== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-reachable=yes
==16296==
==16296== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==16296== ERROR SUMMARY: 56 errors from 56 contexts (suppressed: 19 from 8)
```

This came about as I'm using ALSA in a project and started seeing this huge leak...or at least the report of said leak.

So the question is: is it me, ALSA or valgrind that's having issues here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://git.alsa-project.org/?p=alsa-lib.git;a=blob;f=MEMORY-LEAK;hb=HEAD says:

> ```
>                           Memory leaks - really?
>                           ----------------------
> ```
>
> Note that some developers are thinking that the ALSA library has some memory
>   leaks. Sure, it can be truth, but before contacting us, please, be sure that
>   these leaks are not forced.
>
> The biggest reported leak is that the global configuration is cached for
>   next usage. If you do not want this feature, simply, call
>   snd_config_update_free_global() after all snd_*_open*() calls. This function
>   will free the cache.

Answer (score 1):

The biggest reported leak is that the global configuration is cached for next usage.

If you do not want this feature, simply call `snd_config_update_free_global()` after all `snd_*_open*()` calls.

This function will free the cache."   <---- Valgrind still detects leaks.

This can be fixed if you call `snd_config_update_free_global()` **after**  `snd_pcm_close(handle);`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this will work ([source](http://git.alsa-project.org/?p=alsa-lib.git;a=commitdiff;h=edcd677bf2065c560ef578940bab8f0aacddf0e6)):

```
diff --git a/src/pcm/pcm.c b/src/pcm/pcm.c

--- a/src/pcm/pcm.c
+++ b/src/pcm/pcm.c
@@ -2171,7 +2171,12 @@ static int snd_pcm_open_conf(snd_pcm_t **pcmp, const char *name,
        if (open_func) {
                err = open_func(pcmp, name, pcm_root, pcm_conf, stream, mode);
                if (err >= 0) {
-                       (*pcmp)->open_func = open_func;
+                       if ((*pcmp)->open_func) {
+                               /* only init plugin (like empty, asym) */
+                               snd_dlobj_cache_put(open_func);
+                       } else {
+                               (*pcmp)->open_func = open_func;
+                       }
                        err = 0;
                } else {
                        snd_dlobj_cache_put(open_func);
```

I tried it myself, but to no avail. My core temp heats up ~10 °F, most likely due to similar memory leak. Here's some of what *valgrind* gave me, even after using the patch above:

```
    ==869== 16,272 bytes in 226 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 103 of 103
    ==869==    at 0x4C28E48: calloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:566)
    ==869==    by 0x5066E61: _snd_config_make (in /usr/lib64/libasound.so.2)
    ==869==    by 0x5066F58: _snd_config_make_add (in /usr/lib64/libasound.so.2)
    ==869==    by 0x50673B9: parse_value (in /usr/lib64/libasound.so.2)
    ==869==    by 0x50675DE: parse_array_def (in /usr/lib64/libasound.so.2)
    ==869==    by 0x5067680: parse_array_defs (in /usr/lib64/libasound.so.2)
    ==869==    by 0x5067A8E: parse_def (in /usr/lib64/libasound.so.2)
    ==869==    by 0x5067BC7: parse_defs (in /usr/lib64/libasound.so.2)
    ==869==    by 0x5067A6F: parse_def (in /usr/lib64/libasound.so.2)
    ==869==    by 0x5067BC7: parse_defs (in /usr/lib64/libasound.so.2)
    ==869==    by 0x5067A6F: parse_def (in /usr/lib64/libasound.so.2)
    ==869==    by 0x5067BC7: parse_defs (in /usr/lib64/libasound.so.2)
```

The number of bytes lost just keeps going up and up.