# How to correctly close and free ALSA resources

Tags: c, valgrind, alsa

How to correctly close and free ALSA (and hw params) resources?
I found many examples. All different. All have memleak.

For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <alsa/asoundlib.h>

int
main()
{
    snd_pcm_t *dev;

    snd_pcm_open(&dev, "default", SND_PCM_STREAM_PLAYBACK, 0);
    snd_pcm_close(dev);

    return 0;
}
```

Valgrind report:

```
==19586== LEAK SUMMARY:
==19586==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==19586==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==19586==      possibly lost: 65,525 bytes in 2,020 blocks
==19586==    still reachable: 298 bytes in 6 blocks
==19586==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==19586== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
==19586== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-reachable=yes
==19586== 
==19586== ERROR SUMMARY: 116 errors from 116 contexts (suppressed: 4 from 4)
--19586-- 
--19586-- used_suppression:      2 dl-hack3-cond-1
--19586-- used_suppression:      2 glibc-2.5.x-on-SUSE-10.2-(PPC)-2a
==19586== 
==19586== ERROR SUMMARY: 116 errors from 116 contexts (suppressed: 4 from 4)
```

UPD:

Without snd_pcm_close() we have 117 errors from 117 contexts )))

Comment: possible duplicate of [alsa - mem leak?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13478861/alsa-mem-leak)

Comment: @CL. Where continue discussion? Here? Because still have memleak (2 errors from 2 contexts)

Comment: What are those contexts?

Comment: @CL. http://paste.ofcode.org/ezCMTBPvcLP9SmYanfSv88

Answer (score 1):

You won't obtain leaks if you free the global configuration by calling snd_config_update_free_global() AFTER snd_pcm_close(handle);

Comment: Thanks. But this is bug of alsa on Debian 6. Not actual today - old old stable is gone :)

Answer (score 0):

Tested this example with alsalib 1.1.4.1:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <alsa/asoundlib.h>

int main()
{
    snd_pcm_t *dev;

    snd_pcm_open(&dev, "default", SND_PCM_STREAM_PLAYBACK, 0);
    snd_pcm_close(dev);
    snd_config_update_free_global();

    return 0;
}
```

Adding snd_config_update_free_global() as suggested by Paolo, valgrind is displaying a lot of warnings like this:

```
4,320 bytes in 60 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 91 of 94
```

And the summary is displaying possibly lost blocks:

```
==499== LEAK SUMMARY:
==499==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==499==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==499==      possibly lost: 43,011 bytes in 1,311 blocks
==499==    still reachable: 111,131 bytes in 128 blocks
==499==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==499== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
==499== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all
```

What can be done with that?